# IntelliJ/PhpStorm: How to search 'Not in path'

Tags: phpstorm

Is there any possibility to search for a string but this string **shouldn't** occur in a specific path in PhpStorm?

Comment: Yes, I see 2 ways: 1) create custom Scope that will either include all wanted locations .. or exclude all unwanted and then use it in "Find in Path" 2) Search everywhere but use "Open in Find Window" button -- that will open ALL matches (and not just TOP 100) in a standard Search Results tool window. Results there are/can be grouped by the file path so you can go and remove unwanted results (whole folder and subnodes) via context menu there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do that.

**If you need to do such search few times/regularly:**

1. Create a custom Scope and either include all wanted locations or exclude all unwanted.

   - https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/configuring-scopes-and-file-colors.html
   - https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/settings-scopes.html
2. Use that scope in the "Find/Replace in Path" popup.

   NOTE: you can access Scopes right from the search popup by clicking on `...` button when "Scope" option is selected:

   [image]

---

**If it's a one time search:**

1. Search everywhere in Find in Path (well, use the most convenient option from already available/default options).
2. Hit **"Open in Find Window"** button at the bottom.

   This will list ALL results (instead of just TOP 100) in a standard Find Results tool window, where results are (can be) grouped by the file/folder:

   [image]
3. You can now collapse all and quickly scan your results and remove any results from unwanted locations via context menu:

   [image]